# Retrieving an encrypted value when presented with the plaintext

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, initialization-vector

I am required to use AES 256 CBC to encrypt some strings before I store them in a relational database. I prepend the ciphertext with the IV that was used. The plaintext is a unique string (what I call the "key") that has a one to one relationship with users in my application.

The problem is that when a user does something, they send the plaintext key and I have to go retrieve any metadata associated with it (such as the user's ID, permissions, etc.). But I've encrypted the key in the database, so I can't just filter like `where encrypted_key = :plain_key`. I want to be able to do this retrieval with only the plaintext key and not require that other data are sent with the plaintext key. (It may be necessary that I do use more information in my query; I'm just seeing if there's some clever way around it).

I could just retrieve ALL encrypted keys in the database, and then iterate over all ciphertexts and parse out the IV, re-encrypt the plaintext key I received from the user with the IV, and see if I find a match. I don't want to have to retrieve all ciphertexts though. If the IV were predictable somehow I could do it, but I don't want to use any part of the plaintext key or associated metadata as the IV.

Comment: Exact for your scenario a typical "login" has two parts - a public "username" and a secret password. When sending some data again along with the username the server searches for the username in the database and then compares (in what way...) the stored (and hopefully fully scrambled) password with the one used for login. BTW: the user is sending his "key" in plaintext ? So it seems not to be so secret...

Comment: @MichaelFehr the actual use case is storing an api key and secret for hmac authentication for a different application. so i need access to the plaintext versions of them, but also need to store them encrypted due to a security request that they arent exposed if my database is compromised. the api that the key/secret come from does not fully encrypt the key/secret; i just need to do it and wanted to see if there was a way so that i dont have to add an extra public identifier for them in my application. hopefully that makes sense

Comment: That's OK but why not use any "id" that is stored in the database beneath the (encrypted) key? Make an index in your database on "id", search the entry and decrypt the encrypted key whenever it is needed.

Comment: @MichaelFehr yes, actually i implemented that to get it working, but i was hoping there was a really slick or clever way of not having to do that.